# Variable for number of lines in a file

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to put the number of lines in a file into an integer variable.

This is how i'm doing it

```
typeset -i x
x=`wc -l $1`
```

where $1 is the command line arg

The problem is that wc -l gives a number and the filename like: 5 blah

Is there a way to only put the number into x?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do `cat $1 | wc -l` instead.

Or `wc -l $1 | cut -d " " -f 1`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain how `cat $1 | wc -l` works? If you don't mind

Comment: Not doubt Oli will update the answer but it's basically that, if `wc` doesn't know the name of its input file (such as when the input is coming in via standard input), it doesn't print it.

Answer (score 20):

```
x=$(wc -l < "$1")
```

This avoids a useless use of `cat` and any forks, and would work on a path containing spaces and even newlines.

Comment: This is the cleanest way and should be the answer. Using cat on a large file is a waste of resources

Comment: wc puts all sorts of whitespace in the output that I don't want.

Comment: `wc -l < "$1"` does not, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
wc -l $1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

with awk

Comment: I mean, if you are going to use awk, `awk 'END{print NR}'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the shell to remove the file name.  This has the advantage of not starting a 2nd process as `cat`, `cut`, `sed` or `awk` :

```
var=$(wc -l _your_file_)
nb_lines=${var%% *}
```

You can also rewrite `nb_lines=${var%% *}` with `nb_lines=${var/ */}, but the 2nd form is less portable being`bash` specific.

**Update**

I read above that some `wc`'s output start with spaces, so the above can be rewritten:

```
#var=$(wc -l _your_file_)
var="   3    file"
var=$(echo $var)
nb_lines=${var%% *}
```

Using `echo` to get rid of the extra spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Or with `sed`...

```
wc -l $1 | sed 's/^ *\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'
```

Or, assuming the first space is the one after the number:

```
wc -l $1 | sed 's/ .*$//'
```

Comment: Hmm, not as _readable_ as the others but I promised myself I'd upvote any solution that uses two or less processes :-) It might have been easier just to delete from the first space onwards: `s/ .*$//` rather than using register substitution.

Comment: :D thanks...  now that I see the other answers it does feel ugly, but was the first thing that popped into my head.  The line starts with spaces, so deleting from the first space wouldn't work.

Comment: `wc` output starts with spaces? What OS are you on? Mine sits flush against the left.

Comment: OSX, I guess another way Mac BSD is funky

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to put line numbers in the file i recommend.

In windows:

```
awk '{print NR " " $s}' filename > ouputfile
```

In Linux:

```
cat -n file > outputfile
```

I segregated them because in windows one cannot run `cat -n` so had to use awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
filename=’test.txt'
line_no=$(cat ${filename} | wc -l)
echo ${line_no}
```